# Paginate a Django Modelformset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, pagination, django-forms

I have a modelformset factory, creating a formset, and I would ideally like to combine it with the pagination function, to only display a set number of forms per page

```
formset = modelformset_factory(access, form=action, exclude=(), extra=0)



def access_list_pagination(request):
    accesslist = access.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(accesslist, 10)

try:
    accesses = paginator.page(page)
    print(accesses)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    accesses = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
 accesses = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'edit/page_access_list.html', {'access_list': accesses})
```

Currently I can get all of the forms to display, but am unable to render a specific subset.

The best way to think of this snippet, is a database of names with an Yes/No column. The goal is to display the name, and allow the user to mark yes or no, with one submit button to update the entire list.

I appreciate all the help, and let me know if can clear anything up or do anything better!